# xamarin forms web view crashed

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

work with a web view however1 when I try to work with the web view

the page is crashed and get this error:
"An unhandled exception occured."

attaching my code:

also I want to know if I navagate with the web view to a Image

XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"             
         x:Class="MashamApp.MImageEditor">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10,10">
            <Button Text="Back" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Clicked="backClicked" />
            <Button Text="Forward" HorizontalOptions="End" Clicked="forwardClicked" />
        </StackLayout>
        <WebView x:Name="Browser" WidthRequest="1000" HeightRequest="1000" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

C#:

```
using Syncfusion.SfImageEditor.XForms;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace MashamApp
{
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class MImageEditor : ContentPage
{
    public MImageEditor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Browser.Source = "http://www.walla.co.il";        
    }

    private void backClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// Check to see if there is anywhere to go back to
    if (Browser.CanGoBack) {
        Browser.GoBack ();
    } else { // If not, leave the view
        Navigation.PopAsync ();
    }
}

private void forwardClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Browser.CanGoForward) {
        Browser.GoForward ();
    }
}


}
}
```

Comment: Could you possibly add your stacktrace?

Comment: On which platform does the crash occur?

Comment: it carashes on andorid how I can where is the stack trace